# AttributeError on google cloud datastore entity object

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

I have an entity called Author. Below is the ndb class:

```
class Author(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    website = ndb.StringProperty()
    bio = ndb.StringProperty()
    profile_image_url = ndb.StringProperty()
    slug = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: make_slug(self.name))
```

I am creating an author object like this

```
author = Author(id=pk, **author_dict)
author.put()
```

There is no error when creating an author object for the first time.

I am retrieving an author object like this

```
author = Author.get_by_id(pk)
```

when I try to access the author bio field I get an AttributeError

```
author.bio = bio_text
```

The error comes when accessing a field on a existing author object. Error does not come on all fields.

The console is showing all the columns. The bio column is present in the datastore console for author entity.

I deleted all the author entities and made new entries. Still I am getting AttributeError.

I have several entities in datastore but I am getting this error only for Author entity.

Error statement:

```
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", 
line 2990, in _set_attributes
prop = getattr(cls, name)  # Raises AttributeError for unknown properties.
AttributeError: type object 'Author' has no attribute 'bio'
```

CLOSED:

I had a class called Author in another module. This class was being used by NDB somehow to create the author entity and was causing this behaviour.

Comment: Please can you provide an [mcve].  I can't reproduce this problem with the example code that you have provided.

Comment: Hi, I have added some more information. I can add the surrounding code but it is unrelated to the error.

Comment: You can only get this error if "author" is a class, not an instance, and is a class that does not have a `bio` attribute.  So it seems that you are overwriting `author` somewhere in your code.

Comment: You could try printing or logging `type(author)` and `author.__name__` just before the line that's failing, to see what `author` actually is.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and no matter what fields I have in the Author class, type(Author) is printing Author<author_id=StringProperty('author_id'), name=StringProperty('name'), profile_image_url=StringProperty('profile_image_url')>

Comment: and author.__name__ is giving attribute error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110653/discussion-between-snakecharmerb-and-zaphod100-10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a class called Author in another module. This class was being used as a structured property in another entity class.

Somehow this class was being used by NDB to create the Author entity. I renamed this class and the error was gone.

Now I am using different class names for all ndb entities and structured properties.